# `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "..." -Method Get | select X,Y` doesn't return any row while `(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "..." -Method Get) | select X,Y` does?

Tags: powershell

I have a rest api which will return rows. However,

Why `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "..." -Method Get | select XXX,YYY` returns just header?

```
XXX YYY
--- ---
```

but `(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "..." -Method Get) | select X,Y` returns rows?

Assigning to a variable first also works.

```
$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "..." -Method Get | select XXX,YYY
$x | select xxx,yyyy
```

Comment: when used as shown, the `Select-Object` cmdlet DOES NOT filter objects  - _it creates new objects_. that means that if you specify a property that does not exist in the input object, it will simply make a new, blank object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking:

- **If a command outputs *collections as single objects*, `Select-Object X, Y` won't work as expected**, because it'll look for those properties on the *collection* object, where they can't be found, in which case `Select-Object` creates a *single* object with the requested properties, all of which then contain `$null`.

  - `Invoke-RestMethod` is a likely candidate for this behavior, because it may implicitly parse the return value as JSON via **`ConvertFrom-Json`**, which indeed **outputs *arrays* as *single objects***; this surprising behavior is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424).
- **Placing `(...)` around a command *forces enumeration***, so that may solve the problem:

```
# Place (...) around the Invoke-RestMethod call to force enumeration.
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "..." -Method Get) | select XXX,YY
```

---

**Another option is to assign to an (intermediate) *variable***, as shown in your question - though the `(...)` approach is simpler, if you don't actually need to store the intermediate result.

```
# Store array in a variable.
$array = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "..." -Method Get

# An array stored in a variable sent through the pipeline is 
# invariably enumerated.
$array | select X,Y
```

This works, because sending an array *stored in a variable* through the pipeline *always* enumerates it (sends it elements one by one).

**By *assigning to a variable* you effectively obliterate the distinction between a command that outputs N objects *one by one* and one that outputs *an N-element array* as a *single object*:**

```
# Send an array *as a whole* through the pipeline.
PS> (Write-Output -NoEnumerate (1..3) | Measure-Object).Count
1 # That is, the 3-element array was sent as *one* object

# Wrapping the command in (...) forces enumeration.
PS> ((Write-Output -NoEnumerate (1..3)) | Measure-Object).Count
3  # elements were sent *one by one*

# Store output-as-a-whole array in a variable,
# then send the variable through the pipeline - 
# which also forces enumeration.
PS> $array = Write-Output -NoEnumerate (1..3); ($array | Measure-Object).Count 
3  # elements were sent *one by one*
```

---

Conversely, **if you *do* want to send an array stored in a variable *as a whole* through the pipeline**, you have two options:

```
$array = 1..3

# Use Write-Output -NoEnumerate:
PS> (Write-Output -NoEnumerate $array | Measure-Object).Count
1 # array was sent *as a whole*

# Alternatively - faster and more concise, but more obscure -
# wrap the array in an aux. wrapper array, so that only 
# the wrapper array is enumerated, sending the original array
# as a whole:
PS> (, $array | Measure-Object).Count
1 # array was sent *as a whole*
```

Comment: These are the part of powershells confused design.